# Python Port Scanner, User Input

Tags: python, sockets, port

Working on a simple port scanner that allows user to input an IP address as well as a set of ports to scan through ie a lower boundary port and an upper boundary port inclusive, the program should scan through every port within these boundaries.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import ssl      #secure shell layer
import socket

try:
  ip = sys.argv[1]
  lowport = int(sys.argv[2])
  upport = int(sys.argv[3])
except:
  print 'you did it wrong'
  sys.exit()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(10.0)

def scan(port):
  try:
    s.connect((ip, port))
    return True
  except:
    return False
  s.close()

for x in range(lowport,upport+1):
  if scan(x):
    print "Port {} open" .format(x)
```

however, my output seems suspect. The following are the reported open ports on three different runs.

```
Port 7250 open
Port 7251 open
```

```
Port 22 open
Port 23 open
```

```
Port 5004 open
Port 5005 open
```

I suspect my issue may be in my def scan() block though I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. If I am able to connect to a socket, that means the port is open right? 
working in Python 2.7

Comment: You never close the port.

Comment: is that what would be causing my issue? I put the close method in my try block but I guess it's not reaching that point?

Comment: you have to close before you use `return`. `return` ends function at once.